# change DropDownList list with No Refresh Page and fileupload in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, visual-studio-2015, updatepanel

I use UpdatePanel control for not refresh page in change DropDownList items. also, I use FileUpload outside the UpdatePanel control.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode= "Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
                    Country:
                            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" ViewStateMode="Enabled" DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Key" Autopostack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
                    City:
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" ClientIDMode="Static" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="CityID" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </ContentTemplate>  
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">
                        Image:
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                        <asp:FileUpload ClientIDMode="Static" ID="fuPic" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But its not working for change DropDownList item.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the update isn't being triggered, try adding autopostBack="True" to the dropdown
Edit: your aspx code looks like it should work, the problem is probably in the codebehind.
Edit: you could also try added explicit triggers to the updatepanel.
try adding the triggers, I corrected the spelling on autopostback.

Comment: Excuse me, I did not copy the codes correctly. I use this code and update code. Plase help me